# Database schema for multiple Image upload

Tags: php, mysql

How do I design a table so as to group multiple picture upload at an instance so as to fetch and display them with a single query on a news feed?

I currently have a PHP script that is used to upload a single image along with text and my database table look as follows:

```
___________________________________________________
| Id | user_id | s_pix | m_pix | l_pix| created_at|
___________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='file' name='image[]'/>
post form collect in variable $image

for($i=0;$i<count($image);$i++){
sql="insert into table(column-name)values('".$image[$i]."')";

}
```

Comment: Thanks but what I want is workable and efficient table design.